# Configure Sonarqube with SSL with NGINX as reverse-proxy - Errorcode: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: ssl, nginx, sonarqube

I am trying to configure `Sonarqube` that it works with SSL. I followed the following instructions:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/operate-server/

Below is my configuration:

```
server { 
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-6.7.7/web/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name sonar;

    location / {
              root /var/www/sonar;
              proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
     }
}
```

I have tested my SSL-Certificate and it works fine with a website, that I have created, but with Sonar it is not working.

Below is the error what I get in the Firefox browser:

> Errorcode: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Comment: You don't have any certificates in the configuration which makes it impossible to be used with SSL. Please check your nginx error log which likely points out the issue. The strange `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` is a result of the server not responding with SSL while the client expects a SSL response. *"I followed the following instructions..."* - these instructions only document reverse proxy setup for HTTP and not HTTPS.

Comment: The URL's that are sended to SonarQube can be quite long. Be sure there are no restrictions on that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your answers. @Steffen Ullrich: you are right.

```
server { 
listen 9090 ssl;
ssl_certificate <CERT_NAME>.pem;
ssl_certificate_key <DOMAIN>.key;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ...;
ssl_dhparam <DHPARAM>.pem;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

server_name sonar;

location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
          proxy_redirect http://localhost:9000 https://<DOMAIN.net>:9090;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_request_buffering off;
 }
```

}

Thank you all for your help.